# Ensuring two metavariables aren't unified to the same result

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to write a tactic which will automatically pick up inconsistencies in `Setoid`-based hypotheses.

For instance, If I have the following hypotheses,

```
  H1 : x == y
  H2 : z == y
  H3 : x =/= z
```

I would like to be able to solve this with some combination of `exfalso`, `apply`, `transitivity`, and `symmetry`. When using this tactic:

```
  match goal with
    [ eq1 : ?X == ?Z |- _ ] =>
    match goal with
      [ eq2 : ?Y == ?Z |- _ ] =>
        match goal with
          [ eq3 : ?X =/= ?Y |- _ ] => exfalso; apply eq3; [...]

        end
    end
  end.
```

`eq1` and `eq2` will be bound to the same hypothesis. Is there any way to ensure that `?X` and `?Y` are unified to distinct variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the fact that `eq1` and `eq2` are bound to the same hypothesis is not a problem, because `match` backtracks when it chooses a failing branch.  Here is a proof that discharges a similar goal, with setoid equality being replaced by Leibniz equality:

```
Lemma test T (x y z : T) : x = y -> z = y -> x <> z -> False.
Proof.
intros.
match goal with
| eq1 : ?X = ?Y |- _ =>
  match goal with
  | eq2 : ?Z = ?Y |- _ =>
    match goal with
    | eq3 : ?X <> ?Z |- _ => destruct (eq3 (eq_trans eq1 (eq_sym eq2)))
    end
  end
end.
Qed.
```

Note that this could also have been written in a more compact form:

```
Lemma test T (x y z : T) : x = y -> z = y -> x <> z -> False.
Proof.
intros.
match goal with
| eq1 : ?X = ?Y,
  eq2 : ?Z = ?Y,
  eq3 : ?X <> ?Z |- _ => destruct (eq3 (eq_trans eq1 (eq_sym eq2)))
end.
Qed.
```

**Edit**

If you absolutely want to prevent overlapping matches early, you can also use the `fail` tactic to force backtracking:

```
Lemma test T (x y z : T) : x = y -> z = y -> False.
Proof.
intros.
match goal with
| eq1 : ?X = ?Y |- _ =>
  match goal with
  | eq2 : ?Z = Y |- _ =>
    match Z with
    | X => fail 1
    | _ => idtac eq1 eq2
    end
  end
end.
Abort.
```

If Coq binds `eq1` and `eq2` to the same hypothesis, the first branch of the third `match` will activate and call `fail 1`.  This has the effect of choosing the next branch in the second-closest backtracking point -- in this case, the *second* `match`, which binds `eq2`.  Running this code prints two different hypothesis names in the response buffer.

(If you replace `fail 1` by `fail 0` (or simply `fail`), Coq will instead choose the next branch of the closest backtracking point, which is the third `match`.  Since the next branch accepts all values, it will run `idtac eq1 eq2` no matter what, which on my machine ends up printing `H0 H0`.)

Note that in your example, you could have also matched `eq1` and `eq2` simultaneously to prevent them from being equal.  For instance, the following snippet, which tries to force this equality, fails:

```
Lemma test T (x y z : T) : x = y -> z = y -> False.
Proof.
intros.
match goal with
| eq1 : ?X = ?Y,
  eq2 : ?Z = ?Y |- _ =>
    match Z with
    | X => idtac eq1 eq2
    end
end.
Abort.

(* Error: No matching clauses for match. *)
```

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't realize that match syntax. Is there no way in general to prevent overlapping unification?

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate that you both solved my particular problem and helped me understand the general case.